# Mongo C# driver not serializing collection item Id property

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver

When I try to store some object as part of an collection associated to some parent document, when the whole object has an `Id` property, it doesn't get serialized.

Before asking a new question, I've found this other Q&A from 2011: [Maintain Id property name in embedded doc with mongo C# driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523742/maintain-id-property-name-in-embedded-doc-with-mongo-c-sharp-driver)

As the OP in that Q&A was asking, I've tried to manually configure the `Id` property mapping and I got no luck: `Id` is missing once the objects within the collection are serialized and stored to Mongo.

**As of 2016, is there a <strike>workaround</strike> solution for this?** I want to avoid the 2011's solution of renaming my class property because I don't want to take design decisions based on data source implementation details...